# Good words for 'well-cared-for'?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

What can be some good ways of saying that someone takes good care of himself? I'm looking for words rather than phrases. Someone who is always clean shaven and never has a strand of hair out of place? What do you call such a person?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U Charles!  Please include your research in your question.

Answer (score 15):

**[well groomed](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=well%20groomed%20meaning&hl=en)**
adjective
 (especially of a person) clean, tidy, and smart.
(Google)

or as one word:

[**groomed**](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/groomed) 
adjective
clean and tidy in appearance, clothes, etc
*Even in jeans she managed to look groomed and well-dressed.*
(collinsdictionary.com)

but some dictionaries may not agree that it can stand alone like that.

Comment: Considering the asker's explicit preference for "words rather than phrases", this answer would be better off suggesting simply *groomed*.

Comment: @talmu AHD and Collins have well-groomed as a hyphenated compound, and [even though ODO gives the open form](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/well-groomed), it classes 'well groomed' as 'adjective'. Compound words (even of the open-form variety) are usually regarded as single 'words' (and always as single lexemes).

Comment: @talrnu - *well-groomed* indicates results independent of the process; *groomed*, by itself, suggests to me that that someone else was doing the grooming.

Comment: @bye I agree. They do to me too but, apart from normal usage, I don't see any reason why they should.

Comment: @bye I think it's unusual to assume the adjective *groomed* suggests an outside influence. Consider the example Avon pulled from collinsdictionary.com - it's a stretch to assume it implies the subject isn't responsible for her own appearance. The verb *groom* might make the suggestion you describe, e.g. "He was groomed for presidency," but that word isn't being suggested here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth A fair point. Perhaps we need clarification from the asker to know whether a multi-word lexeme would suffice.

Comment: I've never seen a hyphenated word classed as two words. Classification is tricky when the open form of a compound is available as an alternative.

Comment: @talrnu - *Groomed* is the past tense of a verb; it's not a "hard adjective" (for want of a better term). That's the thing with English; being very lightly inflected, the parts of speech are kind of slippery. And no, it's not at all unusual to assume an outside influence, since the most common usage of the term is the phrase you used. To describe appearance, *well-groomed* and *poorly-groomed* fit common usage. *Groomed* by itself has no positive implication.

Comment: @bye many adjectives start out that way (I reckon), it does get used as an adjective and at least one major dictionary does regard it as an adjective. That should make it "firm" enough for most people's purposes.

Comment: @bye "I was greeted by a groomed doorman." is an example of *groomed* as an adjective (a direct modifier of a noun, to put a more apt definition to your "hard adjective" term). This is clearly a different meaning from "The doorman was groomed for five-star service.", and it's probably even safe to assume that form has a different meaning from "The doorman was groomed." Just because the "groomed for" term is common doesn't mean *groom* by itself is naturally taken to mean "someone else cultivated this person for a role".

Answer (score 9):

I like **[dapper](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dapper#dapper__2)**

> (Of a man) neat and trim in dress and appearance:
>
> *he looked very dapper in a dark silk suit*

This only applies to men, which is okay since you are obviously talking about describing a man.

Women can be **[spruce](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/spruce#spruce-2__2)**

> Neat in dress and appearance:
>
> *Angela was a very spruce and tidy person*

---

Interestingly, you used a good expression in your post that applies here:

[not a hair out of place](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/not-a-hair-out-of-place)

> (Of a person) extremely neat and tidy in appearance.

(Oxford)

Answer (score 4):

You could call such a person:

- hygienic
- clean
- orderly
- fresh
- elegant
- tidy
- immaculate
- well-groomed
- well-kept
- neat

Answer (score 4):

For a single-word, gender-neutral answer, you could choose **immaculate**.

From the [OED](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/immaculate):

> Perfectly clean, neat, or tidy

For example:

> Returning from his grimy hours of manual labour, he dives into a hotel to wash away the dirt, emerging clean and immaculate in a fresh suit and tie.

Answer (score 3):

> > **Sleek**,
> >     adj. : well-groomed and neatly tailored; **especially** **too
> >     well-groomed**.([vocabulary.com](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/sleek))

- Sleek (of hair, fur, or skin) smooth and glossy
- (of a person) having a prosperous appearance ([TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sleek))

> **rakish**, adj. : marked by up-to-dateness in dress and manners

Used as an adjective to **describe a dashing ladies’ man**. Don Juan, the famous Spanish nobleman immortalized in 17th century Spanish tales, is the epitome of rakish: ***stylishly handsome and prone to saucy, fast behavior.*** 
([vocabulary.com](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/rakish))

Answer (score 3):

Consider [*kempt*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/kempt). It suggests active effort is applied to maintain a good appearance. While it doesn't implicitly suggest who is responsible for that maintenance, when used to describe a person's appearance it's generally understood to mean that they take good care of themselves. I've seen it used especially in descriptions of hair, which makes it an excellent fit for your examples.

Answer (score 0):

*Impeccably groomed*. (Dictionary form) Without a flaw.

Answer (score 0):

Dandy; foppish; rake; mannequin; vain; scrubbed; squeaky (clean); flawless; whoopin' (the latter no doubt made up by a dandy friend o' mine)

Comment: Hello, francine, and welcome to the site. Wouldn't you say that some of your suggestions go beyond 'well-groomed' and 'immaculate' to 'ostentatious'?

Comment: _@Edwin ... good point, but being well-groomed IS ostentatious in my neck of the woods!_

Answer (score 0):

For the careful attention to grooming, especially with regard to how he will be perceived by onlookers (hopefully without flaw):  To primp oneself, PRIMPED.